# Attach certificate thumbprint to app registration in Azure using Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, certificate, terraform

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to attach a certificate thumbprint to an app registration using either the azuread or azurerm providers? Currently I can make a valid cert with thumbprint and drop it into my keyvault, as well as make an app registration in Azure AD via terraform, however for the purpose of our apps I would need my app registration to have access to and consume certificates in my keyvault. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this. You will need to have the cert correctly encoded.

```
resource "azuread_application" "application" {
  display_name = "nameofapp"
}

resource "azuread_application_certificate" "application_certificate" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.application.id
  type                  = "AsymmetricX509Cert"
  value                 = file("cert-der-base64.cer")
  end_date              = "2022-02-24T00:00:00Z"
}
```